# Smarty librairies unaccesible by php

Tags: php, ubuntu, smarty

I am installing Smarty on Ubuntu. I follow the installation notice:

- placing libraries under usr/local/lib/php/Smarty;
- creating smarty directories under var/ (as far as I understand, that must not be placed under the web server document root directory);
- creating my project under the root directory var/www/ with a php file for executing the application.

I does not work so far, because, as I suppose, any php file outside the server root directory var/www/ is not readable by php.

How can I manage to both place those libraries .php files outside the root server directory and having them read by php?

Where did I make a mistake?

Thank you for your help.

Victor

Comment: "It does not work" usually implies getting an error message. Can you check for this and add it to your question?

Comment: In fact the server cant access the two folders /template_c and /cache  "FAILED: /var/www/smarty/templates_c is not writable."                    "FAILED: /var/www/smarty/cache is not writable." although I set the access mode to 775. I cannot understand why it does not work.

Comment: The error message says it all: It wants to write to `/var/www/smarty/templates_c` (and `cache`) and isn't allowed to. Assuming these are the directories you want, recheck the permissions for those directories and the user who executes the php scripts (usually `wwwrun` or something similar).